# How to apply custom shipping rate dynamically (on cart and checkout)?

Tags: cart, magento-1, shipping, onepage-checkout, quote

I need to apply free shipping rate to a quote on the fly, once some condition is met. This condition can change when subtotal changes or user logs in/out. Once applied I'd like it to persist from cart to checkout.

I've been trying to set the shipping price from event observers that fire on:

```
<sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after>
<checkout_cart_update_items_before>
```

I tired:

1. Unsetting shipping amount on `$quote->getShippingAddress();`

```
    $address->unsetData('shipping_amount');
    $address->unsetData('base_shipping_amount');
    $address->unsetData('shipping_tax_amount');
    $address->unsetData('base_shipping_tax_amount');
    $address->unsetData('shipping_incl_tax');
    $address->unsetData('base_shipping_incl_tax');
```

This doesn't work because grand total is not being updated.

2. Setting carrier config from the observer:

```
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
    $carriers = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers', $store);

    foreach ($carriers as $carrierCode => $carrierConfig) {
        $store->setConfig("carriers/{$carrierCode}/price", $newPrice);
    }
```

Does not work either.

3. Setting another config from the observer:

```
    $store->setConfig("carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal", $newSubtotal);
```

This nearly worked but not for all cases. E.g. when `$newSubtotal = 15` and actual order subtotal was 14.70 free shipping was applied - what should not happen.

Is there any other way I could do this? Thanks!